# Как считать значение параметра тега HTML в js?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

```
<div style="VALUE" class="letter">
```

как присвоить переменной значение параметра `style` через его класс?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let element = document.querySelector('.rect');

Object.assign(element.style, {
    width: '50px',
    height: '50px',
    background: '#cecece'
});
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var styleValue = document.getElementsByClassName("1");
var a = styleValue[0].getAttribute("style");
document.write(a);
```

```html
<div style="VALUE" class="1">
```

Answer (score -1):

Возможно я не так понял

```js
let e = document.getElementById('d');

function getStyle(elem) {
  let style = '';
  [].forEach.call(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules, function(item) {
    if (item.selectorText == '.' + elem.className)
      style = item.cssText.replace(/.+?{(.+?)}/, '$1');
  });
  return style;
}

e.style.cssText = getStyle(e);
```

```css
.letter {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='d' class='letter'>asd</div>
```